# How to make a box plot in excel which contains two series of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a box plot like this in excel. how it can happen?

[image]

Comment: which version of Excel?

Comment: tried : [Insert chart > All chart > Stock > Open-High-Low-Close ] ?

Comment: How about making two overlapping box plots?